# Is there a notion of maps that can "expand" spaces "linearly"?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

For linear transformations, the dimension of the image is at most the dimension of the domain. More generally, given vectors $v_1, ..., v_n$ in the domain, the vectors $Tv_1, ..., Tv_n$ span the image. So, intuitively, we can only either preserve the dimension of our input space or "collapse" it into a space of smaller dimension.

What I am asking is whether there is a notion of taking a smaller dimensional space and "expanding" it or "extending" it "linearly", e.g. mapping a line to a plane. Is this useful or practical? It seems quite natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a surjective *linear* map $A:V\to W$, where $\dim V<\dim W$ so that $A$ is a "linear extension" of $V$, then this is impossible by the rank-nullity theorem: if $A$ is surjective, then $\dim\operatorname{im}A=\dim W$ and $\dim\ker A=0$, so $\dim W=\dim V$, and in particular we cannot have $\dim V<\dim W$.

More exotic surjective and even continuous maps from spaces of lower dimension to spaces of higher-dimension do exist (see space-filling curves).